# What is a smarter way to get a child control in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have a User Control, containing a Grid, containing a child control.

I want to get a reference to the child control from the code behind for the User Control.

This is what I have:

```
var childControl = (MyChildControlType)this.Grid.Children.Single(c => (string) c.GetValue(NameProperty) == "MyChildControlNameFromXAMLNameAttribute");
```

Ugly as a run over garbage can lid.

What is a neater way to do this?

Comment: "Ugly as a run over garbage can lid." What do you want that element for? XAML elements should not be manipulated in code behind.

Comment: give the child an x:Name property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a Name or x:Name to an element in XAML (unless it is inside a template) makes that element accessible from code-behind as a field with that name. So this is basically already declared and populated for you during InitializeComponent:

```
MyChildControlType MyChildControlNameFromXAMLNameAttribute;
```

and you can use it directly:

```
MyChildControlNameFromXAMLNameAttribute.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: The other stuff still comes in handy if you're not right in the code-behind, looking in a template, etc. just not needed here. :)

Comment: Explains how these fields magically pop up in the code behind: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189028(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could either go with the name-hunting, along the lines of what's been suggested already:

```
var childControl = (MyChildControlType)this.Grid.FindName("MyChildControlNameEtc");
```

Or, if you wanted a more generic approach to what you're already trying (eg if you want to look up by a different property), you could try:

```
var childControl = (MyChildControlType)this.Grid.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().Single(f => f.Name == "Blah");
```

or

```
var childControl = (MyChildControlType)this.Grid.Children.OfType<MyChildControlType>().Single(f => f.Name == "Blah");
```

Or you could use the VisualTreeHelper, which would work with non-Grids, and would particularly work nicely if you needed to recurse down the visual tree:

```
for(int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this.Grid); ++i)
{
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.Grid, i) as FrameworkElement;
    if (child != null && child.Name == "Blah")
        return child;
}
```

But really if you can just name it and access it from the codebehind normally like what John Bowen said that's by far the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

May be this , Give x:Name to your childControl

```
 var childControl = (MyChildControlType)MyGridNameFromXAMLNameAttribute.FindName("MyChildControlNameFromXAMLNameAttribute");
```