# Assigning identifiers to elements through a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

Let's assume we're binding a listview to

`List<string> Titles;`

like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" />
        </DateTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And I want to be able to give the button in the data template an identifier based on its respective title, the following won't compile since the Name variable must be given a string and will not accept a binding, but it's what I want to get to:

```
<Button Name="{Binding}" />
```

Is there any way to do this so that in the back end we would be able to find the button using the identifier assigned to it via a binding?

Comment: By the "element" do you mean the button or the string in Titles?

Comment: @toadflakz When I say element, I'm referring to the button.

Comment: Okay. Why would you need the button? I ask because if you're doing event-based handling for Click on the individual buttons, you're doing XAML programming the extremely painfully hard way.

Comment: You can only do that programmatically, but @toadflakz is correct, in WPF we don't generally need UI elements to have identifiers, so you are probably taking the wrong approach to your main goal.

Comment: @toadflakz, Sheridan This is more out of curiosity than anything else, I'm just messing around with a pet application and found this "barrier" which normally wouldn't even exist on a normal project.

Comment: You wouldn't work with the UI this way, which is why it's not like "normal" projects. The entire point of XAML's Binding subsystem is to enable the abstraction of the View (UI) from the Model data underneath, including business logic which runs on that Model. It's also only "normal" relative to an event-driven UI paradigm which XAML is not specifically even tho' it does have events.

Comment: @toadflakz I'm aware of that, and I'm in complete agreement with you. To use such an approach with XAML in a real project would be a farce, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using the techniques described in this answer: [What is a smarter way to get a child control in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825232/what-is-a-smarter-way-to-get-a-child-control-in-xaml)

Specifically:

```
var childControl = this.ListView.Children.OfType<Button>().Single(f => f.Content == "Blah");
```

..where "Blah" is one of the items in Titles to be an exact match.